# I removed my app module in android studio and now I can't compile

Tags: android, module, compilation

I was adding a library to my project in "Module Settings". I decided I didn't need it after all and when going to remove it, I went on my app module and removed it instead... Now I can't compile or run my app!

What do I have to do in order to have it working again? When I go in "Android" view instead of "Project" as shown in the picture, there is nothing to show.

Help please!

[image: Android studio's view]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not have removed the library from module dependencies. If that is the problem then goto File -> Project Structure and select your "app" module in the left. There select Dependencies (last one) and if the library which you no longer use is still there click on it and click on the "-" below to remove the dependency.

P.S: It might be helpful if you pasted the kind of error you get.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but i encountered the same problem and solved by adding

```
include ':app'
```

in settings.gradle.

Let the project sync and the problem will be gone.